# Direct proof of decomposition of real vector bundle of odd degree into the direct sum of a trivial bundle and another of even degree

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

The real splitting principle tells us that when taking a real, oriented vector bundle of odd dimension $\zeta$ over a manifold $M$ you can always write $\zeta$ as $\tilde{\zeta} \oplus \varepsilon^1$, where $\dim\tilde{\zeta} = \dim \zeta - 1$ and $\varepsilon^1$ is the trivial bundle over $M$, that is, $\varepsilon^1 = M \times \mathbb{R}$ with the projection on the first factor. Is there an easy way to show this directly?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not what I would call the real splitting principle, and also it is not true. What is true is the following:

- A real oriented vector bundle $V$ splits as above iff it has a nowhere vanishing section iff its Euler class $e(V)$ vanishes. (**Edit, 4/30/21:** As Georges says in the comments, this is incorrect; whoops! Fortunately what is true, and what is needed for the rest of the argument in this answer, is that if an oriented vector bundle has a nowhere vanishing section then its Euler class vanishes.)
- If $V$ is odd-dimensional, then $V$ is isomorphic as an oriented vector bundle to the same vector bundle but with the opposite orientation, and since reversing the orientation reverses the Euler class, we have $e(V) = - e(V)$, or $2e(V) = 0$.

But it is possible for the Euler class of a real oriented odd-dimensional vector bundle to be a nontrivial $2$-torsion class. Since $e(V) \equiv w_n(V) \bmod 2$, it suffices to exhibit a $3$-dimensional real orientable vector bundle whose top Stiefel-Whitney class $w_3$ does not vanish. By the splitting principle, if an example exists, then an example exists which is a direct sum of three line bundles. The Stiefel-Whitney classes $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in H^1(-, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ of these line bundles must satisfy

$$\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 0$$

(for orientability) and

$$\alpha \beta \gamma \neq 0$$

(because this is the top Stiefel-Whitney class $w_3$ and we don't want it to vanish). We can find classes in $H^1(-, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ with this property on $M = \mathbb{RP}^2 \times \mathbb{RP}^2$. By the Kunneth formula,

$$H^{\bullet}(M, \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2[\alpha, \beta]/(\alpha^3 = \beta^3 = 0)$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the Stiefel-Whitney classes of the tautological bundles $L_{\alpha}, L_{\beta}$ on the first and second copy of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ respectively. Take $\gamma = \alpha + \beta$. The resulting direct sum of line bundles

$$V = L_{\alpha} \oplus L_{\beta} \oplus (L_{\alpha} \otimes L_{\beta})$$

is a $3$-dimensional real orientable (because $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 0$ vanishes by construction) vector bundle with top Stiefel-Whitney class

$$w_3(V) = \alpha \beta (\alpha + \beta) = \alpha^2 \beta + \alpha \beta^2 \neq 0$$

as desired.

Comment: Why is it sufficient in general that $w_n \neq 0$? I agree it works in this case, because $H^3(M)$ is 2-torsion, but I don't see why one can't have, say, $e(V)$ not be a torsion element but $w_n$ be nonzero.

Comment: @Mike: the goal here was just to exhibit an odd-dimensional vector bundle whose Euler class doesn't vanish, to show the OP that the statement they wanted to prove was not true. It's extra icing on the cake that in fact the Euler class must be $2$-torsion (which follows from the second bullet point).

Comment: Sure. I think I just misread what you were saying there; sorry.

Comment: Your first bullet point is not correct: there exists a non-trivial rank $3$ vector bundle $V$ on $S^4$ without any trivial line sub-bundle. That bundle is orientable (since the $4$-sphere is simply connected)  and its Euler class $e(V)\in H^3(S^4, \mathbb Z)=0$ is of course zero. For details see Bott-Tu's book, Example 23.16, page 302.

Comment: @Georges: whoops. Fortunately we only need one direction here.

Comment: Yes, and thanks for your quick answer to my comment.