# Is Euler class independent of oriented trivializations

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $\pi: E \to M$ be an orientable vector bundle. Suppose that $\{U, f_{\alpha}\}$ consists of oriented trivializations(meaning the determinant $f_{\alpha}f_{\beta}^{-1}$ is positive on fibers. Is Euler class dependent on the choice of such trivializations?

Suppose that $\{U, g_{\alpha}\}$ consists of another set of oriented trivializations. But the determinant of $g_{\alpha} f_{\beta}^{-1}$ is negative. Then in my opinion integration along each fiber will give me opposite answers with respect those two choices simply by change of variables theorems(thus leading to opposite Thom class and Euler class). But this does not seem to be correct. What is wrong here?

PS: everything is over $\mathbb R$

Comment: The definition of Euler class on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_class depends explicitly on a choice of orientation

Comment: But according to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268751/direct-proof-of-decomposition-of-real-vector-bundle-of-odd-degree-into-the-direc $e(E) = e(-E) = -e(E)$, @JaneDoé

Comment: Both Thom classes and Euler classes depend on orientation.

Comment: Then why does the claim in the link hold? @JuanDiegoRojas

Comment: In that particular case $E$ admits an isomorphism of oriented vector bundles between the same vector bundle but with opposite orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Thom classes and Euler classes depend on orientation. You could see this more intuitively by using the properties of the Thom class and Euler class with respect to integration. For instance, the Thom class $\Phi_E\in H_{cv}(E)$ satisfies that integration along every fiber is $1$. However, if fibers are oriented with the opposite orientation, integration along the fiber would yield $-1$ in every fiber. Therefore, $\Phi_{-E} = -\Phi_E$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is also what I figured. Would you please explain the link in more detail assuming odd rank? I am confused as to what bundle isomorphism is referred to there.

Comment: One thing is an isomorphism of vector bundles and another one is an isomorphism of oriented vector bundles. The former is a diffeomorphism that fiberwise is a linear isomorphism. The latter is the same, but fiberwise is an orientation preserving linear isomorphism. That is, it sends the chosen orientation in one fiber to the chosen orientation in the other. The fact used in the post is the following: if $E$ is an oriented vector bundle of odd-rank and $E'$ is the same vector bundle but with opposite orientation, then there exists an isomorphism of oriented vector bundles between $E$ and $E'$.